# Abstract class issue

Tags: java, android, abstract-class

I am creating one parent Activity(Class) and then want to extends this class to another Activity(Class). I have some controls in all the Activities(Classes) so I decide to use Abstract class so that I need not write some common code in all the classes.I created below classes and one of it is abstract class.When I am calling my Welcomepage Activity this will display me a screen with all common controls(Radio buttons in my case).In Abstract class I had set `checkedChangedListener`  listener and in `onCheckedChanged()` method I am creating a toast but It is not displaying.I am confused in this case.What is the reason to not displaying a toast?.

**My Activity(Class) Welcomepage_pillReminder which extends CustomTabsActivity**

```
public class Welcomepage_pillReminder extends CustomTabsActivity

    @Override
    public void mappingWidgets() {
        super.mappingWidgets();

    }

@Override
    public void addCheckChangedListner() {
        super.addCheckChangedListner();
    }
```

**CustomActivity**

```
public abstract class CustomTabsActivity extends Activity {
    protected RadioButton radHome;

    public void mappingWidgets(){
        radHome = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radHome);
    }
    public void addCheckChangedListner() {
        radHome.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onCheckedChangeListener);
    }


    OnCheckedChangeListener onCheckedChangeListener = new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if(isChecked) {
                if(buttonView.getText().equals("Home")) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Home", 2000).show();
                }   
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: When adding code please try to keep it as small as possible (i.e. no extra stuff that doesn't help the problem).

Comment: Since you are using inner class inside an abstract class that might be cause.since in java we can nor instantiate abstract class then inner class inside the abstract class will be causing the problem.

Comment: Ohh I forgot to call method after overriding `mappingWidgets()` and `addCheckChangedListner()`. in `onCreate()` method .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this,

**Your CustomActivity.java**

```
public class CustomActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    public void initLayout(Button button){
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
     public void simple_method(){
            System.out.println("test in CustomActivity");
        }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Button Clicked in Custom Activity", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Activity that extends CustomActivity
**CustomClassDemoActivity.java**

```
  public class CustomClassDemoActivity extends CustomActivity{
    Button button;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
        button.setText("This is a Custom Activity Example");
        super.initLayout(button);
        simple_method();
    }

    public void simple_method(){
        super.simple_method();
        System.out.println("test in mainClass");
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        super.onClick(v);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Button Clicked in Main Activity", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: I forgot to call method after overriding mappingWidgets() and addCheckChangedListner(). in onCreate() method . After seeing your answer I have solve my issue.Thanks.

Comment: You are right and your answer has help me a lot but there is no need to pass any widget in Abstract class.I just want to call abstract class methods and it is done.Your answer is right so I am accepting it.Again thank you for helping me.

Comment: Well I had passed the button instance because I was trying to add a listener in the custom class.

Answer (score 0):

For your purpose the using of an abstract class dosent make sense.

An abstract class only declares its methods and the concrete class can implement the method then depending on its purpose. It would make sense if you plan to write various classes which extend your activity and each of them would have another implementation purpose for `mappingWidgets()` and `addCheckChangedListner()`.

In your case a simple class which will be extended would do the job.

Furthermore I see, that you use the `@Override` annotation in your sub class. With this annotation you override your methods.

At first, please remove the `@Override` in your methods of the sub class. I guess they will work then.

Maybe also reconsider when usin abstract classes and / or `@Override`.

Comment: Thanks for help.I get the solution If I just call the override methods it will work so that I don't need to repeat same code in all activities.

Comment: Your welcome. If you implement sub classes that inherit common method from a main activity class, please make sure, that each sub class has its own `onCreate` method. Also declare the regarding sub class as the activity class in your Android Manifest.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to call function `mappingWidgets()` and `addCheckChangedListner()` after calling this two method my code works fine.Thanks all for help me.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.welcome_pillminder);
        mappingWidgets();
        addCheckChangedListner();
    }
```